# storing and passing long numeric strings in node & jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

(newbie here)

i have large floating-point arrays created by node.js  that i need to pass to s client-side jquery-ajax function.  the goal is download it the fastest way possible.

we can safely round off the floating-point to the hundredth position, maybe even the tenth position - but i still need to experiment to see which one works best.

so far i have multiplied each array value by 100 and rounded off to just have three digits:

```
wholeNbrValue = Math.round(floatingPointValue * Math.pow(10, 3));
```

so for example 0.123456 would become 123. then each set of digits is appended to a string:

```
returnString += sprintfJs('%03d', wholeNbrValue)      ;
```

i end up with a rather long ascii string of digits.   then i might use something like fs.createWriteStream to store the string on the server as an ordinary file, and later use jquery-ajax to fetch it on the client side.

my question:  what might be the optimum way to store a numeric only string?  i am tempted to loop back through the string again and use something like charCodeAt() and just grab up every two positions as an ascii value, or even grab every 64 digits and convert it to a four-byte hex value.

or perhaps is there some way using node to actually store a binary floating-point array and later retrieve it with jquery-ajax?

thank you very much.

Comment: Why complicated that much ? I'm pretty sure you can easily pass 100k+ numeric data as raw javascript pretty fastly.

Comment: Keep it numeric digits, and gzip the response.  It'll be pretty small that way.  If you need it faster, you could try converting your fraction to the nearest multiple of 1/128th and convert the multiple to a byte, but I'm not sure that would be much smaller than a string of digits gzipped. `returnString+=String.fromCharCode(Math.round(floatingPointValue*128));`

Comment: reversing the process is easy as well... `for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  array[i]=string.charCodeAt(i)/128;
}`

Comment: excellent suggestion - thank you very much.   i am surprised you didnt post this as an answer.  your suggestion of using gzip lead me express/compression that looks like it will work too.